# deleting animation doesn't show up

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview, delete-row

I have UIViewController and I dragged a UITableView inside and I want to insert some elements to the table and be able to remove them here . When I use this code it works fine for UITableViewController but now when I want to remove a cell I can swap it but the deleting animation (Red sign) doesn't show up

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

    var listArray = ["Danial"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBOutlet var table: UITableView!

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return listArray.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell.textLabel?.text = listArray[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> Bool
    {
        return true
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
            listArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
     tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are typing:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        listArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
 tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)        }
}
```

instead of

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){
        listArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
 self.table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)        }
}
```

so just go to everywhere where you wrote

```
tableView.
```

and change it to `self.table. 
(basically what you named your tableview from the IBOutlet)`

Comment: oh... my bad but even when I correct that  one still can't get the red sign . Do u know why ? :)

Comment: I caught my second mistake it was that i didn't define any constrains so it was just off the screen XD  , but thanks a lot for your help  ;)